# Laptop gets slow when unplugged?

Tags: laptop

Im using a laptop, with almost newest drivers, Windows 7, 64 bit. I noticed that when it is accidentally remove it from the connector, it becomes slow, even I plug it back immediatly. If I reboot, it works OK again.

Answer (score 5):

This could be because of the Power Saving configuration. Check it and see what is set for the battery mode. It would probably have a lower percentage of use for the CPU.

[image]

Comment: everything is on 100% and the same

Comment: @JohnSmith do you have any manufacturer's *software* that controls the power saving? I think that the issue is power saving-related.